Flatten bottom $n$ levels
The documentation for Flatten states:

Flatten[list,n] – flatten out the top $n$ levels in list

Does a function exist to flatten out the bottom $n$ levels in list?

I don't understand why some are voting to close this as "a simple mistake or easily found in the documentation" without even making a comment.

The most straightforward approach would be to use Map. Consider the following list:
l = {
   {
    {{1}, {2}, {3}},
    {{4}, {5}, {6}}
    },
   {
    {{7}, {8}, {9}},
    {{10}, {11}, {12}}
    }
   };

The flatten this list from level 2 and down, we may run the following:
Map[Flatten, l, {2}]


{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}}

Or from level 1:
Map[Flatten, l, {1}]


{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}}

You can also do it using the third argument of flatten, here is how to do it from level 2:
Flatten[
 l,
 {{1}, {2}, {3, 4}}
 ]


{{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}}

Here is how to do it from level 1:
Flatten[
 l,
 {{1}, {2, 3, 4}}
 ]


{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}}


Though searching intensively before, I now found an answer:
Apply[Sequence, list, {n}]


How is this an answer? Where is the n?

From my point of view this question can be closed

@Domen now n is available

It would be nice if you provide some example inputs with expected outputs in your question (or answer). As it stands, I don't understand how your answer does what you asked for. Alternatively, just delete the entire post, because without clarification it's more confusing than helpful.
